# How to select fiends including a new field which's value is sum of other specific fields with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with mongoose,
and I'd like to select fields including a new field which's value is sum of other specific fields.
For example, there's a model schema like below.

```
const monsterSchema = new Schema({
 name: { type: String },
 power: { type: Number },
 armor: { type: Number },
});
```

I want to select this records having fields 'name', 'power', 'armor', 'total'.
The field has a value as sum of 'power' and 'armor'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework where you can run an aggregation operation with a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step that has the extra computed field as follows (assuming your Mongoose model is named Monster):

```
Monster.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "power": 1,
            "armor": 1,
            "new_field": { "$add": [ "$power", "$armor" ] }     
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    if(err) handleError(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much. By any chance, do you know how I can do that after populate? For example like this, 'Collection.find().populate('_monster').aggregate(.....'. I need not only 'Monster's fields but also 'Collection's fields to create 'new field' that has value as sum of other specific fields.

Comment: Quite possible but as such you would need to create a new question since the question evolves after receiving answers to the original question. Any changes invalidate the answers you've already received, and often negatively impact those users kind enough to answer your question.

Comment: I've just made another question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514079/how-to-aggregate-after-populate-with-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

You can add virtual field to your schema.

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      first: String,
      last: String
    }
});

personSchema.virtual('name.full').get(function () {
   return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

This will not store in document.May this help you.
If you want to know more about this refer below link.

[mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: Thank you! This would be very useful in some cases.